# how to assign new values to literals using z3

Tags: model, z3

There is a set of 4 formulas as these `x - y < 2` `x - y > 2` x > 3`y < 4`.When the first formula is erased, the model of `x=4 y=-1`can be found. How can I substitute x and y with 4 and -1 on the first formula using z3(api)? Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't.  Z3 is a proof-box, not a calculator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Z3_substitute` API. Here is an example using Z3 Python. I'm using Python because it is more convenient and [we can test it online using rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/WcLb). We can write the same example using the Z3 C/C++, .Net, or Java APIs.

```py
x, y = Ints('x y')

s = Solver()
s.add(x - y > 2, x > 3, y < 4)
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m
# We can retrieve the value assigned to x by using m[x].
# The api has a function called substitute that replaces (and simplifies)
# an expression using a substitution.
# The substitution is a sequence of pairs of the form (f, t).
#  That is, Z3 will replace f with the term t.

F1 = x - y < 2

# Let us use substitute to replace x with 10
print substitute(F1, (x, IntVal(10)))

# Now, let us replace x and y with values assigned by the model m.
print substitute(F1, (x, m[x]), (y, m[y]))
```

Comment: Nice!Many thanks. Can the api be applied to the smt2 instances?

Comment: Yes, the SMT2 front-end has an `eval` command. After `(check-sat)`, we can write `(eval (< (- x y) 2))`. It will evaluate the expression in the model produced by Z3.

Comment: Related to SMT2 instances, when we don't know the exactly concrete formulas,such as we found the model m[i] and substitute the formula[i]'s variables, which are not known exactly x1 or x2, with m[i]. Can it also work and how? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Additionally,using *eval* as cout<<eval(formula[i])<<"\n", the concrete value cannot be returned but *false* or *true*